# Windows Service behaves strangely

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

My window service was started on 12.00Am . It will process the data and send a mail saying file exported successfully. we gave time gap as one day. But when we saw mail it was like mail was generated on 12.02 then 12.03 then 12.04 now after 60days its 1.00am
But i want it to start exactly at 12 everyday. problem now looks like it takes 24 hrs from the time mail was generated. please help

Comment: How did you implement the interval?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are adding 24 hours in the time it ran last time to calculate the time it should run.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply schedule your application with Task Scheduler  so you wont have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the time gap of 24 hours, set your interval to something smaller (maybe 1 minute) and keep the date that it was last sent and you'll know when to send when Date.Now.Date > lastRunDate. This will also handle Daylight Saving Time.

Or, are you stopping the timer during the processing? If you are, that could be a source of the lag time.